# Concate two char pointers

Tags: c, pointers, char-pointer

I am just learning C and got to the point of pointers. I wrote a method which should concate two char pointers and I got a strange behavior I just cant explain to myself nor did I find an answer on it, so maybe you can help!

So I don't understand why `stringcat` and `stringptr` point to different addresses, namely ones that are 8 Byte appart. Secondly, I dont understand why I cannot use `stringcat` in the two while-loops on the bottom. I just dont get any output. Also if I use `stringptr[0]` in the last `printf`, there won't be any output.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Edit: This code works, I just don't understand why I cant use `stringcat` on bottom.

Edit2: Noticed some * got missing while copy pasting, so I added them!

```
char stringcat(const char str1, const char* str2){
  char *ptr1 = str1;
  char *ptr2 = str2;
  int count = 0;

  while(*ptr1 != '\0'){
    count++;
    ptr1++;
  }

  while(*ptr2 != '\0'){
    count++;
    ptr2++;
  }

  char *stringcat = malloc((count+1)*sizeof(char));
  char *stringptr = stringcat;

  printf("%d %d", &stringcat, &stringptr);

  ptr1 = str1;
  ptr2 = str2;

  while(*ptr1 != '\0' && (stringptr++ = ptr1++));
  printf("%c", stringcat[0]);
  while(*stringptr++ = *ptr2++);

  return stringcat;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` - Why? It is defined as one

Comment: You have missed adding the null at the end of the string.

Comment: I think this is wrong `stringptr++ = ptr1++` - Better just to do one thing at a time - makes reading the code easier and less prone to bugs

Comment: `char *ptr1 = str1;` is a type error, and so is `char *ptr2 = str2;`.

Comment: @EdHeal: `while ((*p++ = *q++));` is a pretty standard way of writing out `strcpy(q, p)`, it looks like idiomatic C to me.

Comment: Why are these type errors? It works absolutly fine. So does the null get added automaticly, when I use stringptr, but not when I use stringcat? The code written above works, I just can't use stringcat in the while loops. Thanks for the answers! :)

Comment: `(stringptr++ = ptr1++)` -> `(*stringptr++ = *ptr1++)` perhaps

Comment: "*It works absolutly fine.*" - No, it doesn't, and you seem to be completely ignoring all compiler diagnostics. How are you compiling this?

Comment: The * missing is just a typo, sorry for that.

Comment: @F.Zi - Please do not edit the post in such as the answers below stop making sense.

Comment: C does not support _methods_ . And concat**enating** pointers does not make sense. A pointer is not an array  and vice-versa and neither are the same as a string.

Comment: @EdHeal: Sorry for that! Will write it in an Edit note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

```
printf("%d %d", &stringcat, &stringptr);
```

Print the address of the variable stringcat and stringptr which are different, they are allocated into the stack so, presumibly, you are compiling an x64 bit program, so they are 8 bytes apart.

this

```
printf("%d %d", stringcat, stringptr);
```

is what you want.

I just made the minimum amount of change to your code to make it works:

```
char* stringcat(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
    const char *ptr1 = str1;
    const char *ptr2 = str2;
    int count = 0;

    while (*ptr1 != '\0') {
        count++;
        ptr1++;
    }

    while (*ptr2 != '\0') {
        count++;
        ptr2++;
    }

    char *stringcat = (char *)malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char *stringptr = stringcat;

    printf("%d %d", stringcat, stringptr);

    ptr1 = str1;
    ptr2 = str2;

    while (*ptr1 != '\0' && (*stringptr++ = *ptr1++));
    printf("%c", stringcat[0]);
    while (*ptr2 != '\0' && (*stringptr++ = *ptr2++));

    *stringptr++ = '\0';

    return stringcat;
}
```

Comment: This works great thanks! But I still can't change stringptr to stringcat in the two bottom while loops, can you explain to me why it doesnt work?

Comment: An example can explain why:
Assume that stringcat value is 0x100 after malloc, if you use it in the while loop stringcat value is incremented (you use ++ operator inside the loop) so you cannot return the stringcat anymore, you must return the original address 0x100

Comment: Thank you, that was the explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are making a number of errors. Some will be reported by the compiler but you have to turn warnings on.

How will `stringcat` be called and what is it to return? This is the essential (first) question in developing a function.One method is that it gets two strings to concatenate and returns a new string, with the second concatenated to the first. Another method is that it returns the first string with the second concatenated to it.

For the first method, it must allocate new storage that can hold both strings, so that would be `newstring= malloc(strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1);` Don't forget to add 1 for the terminating null of strings.

For the second method, it is essentially the same, except that `str1` must itself have been allocated with malloc because your function will call `free` or `realloc` to re-allocate the storage needed for the (longer) string.

In both cases, the function will look like `char *stringcat(char *str1, char *str2)`. I think with this input you can write the remainder of the function yourself.

Comment: It actually should have been *stringcat(char *str1, char *str2), some of the * just got lost while copy-pasting the code, sorry for that. As for the malloc part, shouldnt be my implementation reserve the same amount of memory or did I got something very wrong? Thank you for answer! :) I still dont understand why the two pointers point to different addresses in memory, you have a clue?

Comment: How did the `const` get included when doing the cut'n'paste?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a char pointer point to a char. The problem is, you don't assign the char variable to pointer, but the address of the char.

So, you should change your:

```
char *ptr1 = str1
```

To:

```
char *ptr1 =&str1
```

This is because the `&var` gets the address of the variable.

Then, you were also using `*stringptr++`, which increments the **value** of the char it's pointing to, instead of the address space.

I would highly recommend you to read the K&R book. It's an excellent book for both newbies, and people who already know C. And indeed, one of the things addressed there is exactly this.

Comment: Yes it was, was an error while copying! Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 0):

Pertaining to question 1, `stringcat` and `stringptr` do point to the address. It is `&stringcat` and `&stringptr` that are different.
By declaring `char *var = malloc(...)`, you are reserving a memory space in the stack, let's say address `30`, for the pointer variable, `var`, and then let `var` contain the address of whatever was malloc-ed, let's say address `200` (which resides in the heap memory).
When you proceed with `char *var2 = var`, you reserve another lot in the stack to store the new pointer variable `var2`, most likely `31`. you then assign `var2` to hold the address that was contained in `var`, which was `200`.
Therefore, the variable in address `30` and `31` would both contain address `200`. By using `&var` what you are getting is actually `30` instead of the `200` you were expecting. Naturally, `&var2` would be different with a value of `31`.

For the second question, it is hard to understand what you were looking for as there were errors in the code as reflected by the other answers.